# Facebook Graph API pre-defined messages, but with the ability to edit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently building a site for a University study that aims to encourage a select few young people (peer supporters) to share messages around health and wellbeing in a private Facebook group.

I have used the Feed/Share dialog to share relevant links/images, however there are a few bits of content that are just pure text. I am aware that Facebook allows to post a status to a group using the Graph API, however you are not allowed to pre-fill what a user is going to say.

Would it be possible to have the ability to generate the content in a text box allowing the users to edit it as they wish before posting to the group or is this still prohibited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...allowing the users to edit it as they wish...

No, that is not allowed, it´s prefilling. You would only be allowed to present an EMPTY textbox, where users can write the message. The message always must be 100% user generated.

Comment: What if I offered a quick ability to copy/paste a piece of content into the message, edit then submit?

Comment: I have just read Platform Policy 2.3 and it seems that users can copy and paste manually into a textbox then submit. Would javascript be allowed for the copying to clipboard part (keeping pasting that text manual)? We are primarily aiming the web app to mobile and it might create some UI issues.

Comment: the textbox must be empty initially, that´s important.